A migration from XAMP to WAMP made a Python script unusable in PHP
I was running PHP on XAMP (Windows) without any issues. The PHP website calls a Python function at some point, which uses a library.
I just changed to WAMP because I needed a newer version to match a remote version installed on a VM and wanted to try WAMP.
It took me a while to make it work, but now it does. Only, now calling the Python script does absolutely nothing. I do have some errors in the Apache logs saying that "The system can't execute the specified program". That's basically it.
Python is in my PATH, I double checked, and Apache connect to System, which has access to PATH variables.
I'm just lost and overwhelmed, I don't know where to look nor what to do.
I tried to delete and add back Python to the PATH. I tried to change the way PHP calls the function :
From this :
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 python/usePyfluids.py $pressure $temp $fluid");
$result = shell_exec($command);

To this (the path for Python is weird but it's working everywhere else) :
    $result = shell_exec("'C:\Users\fcombeau\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python3' python/usePyfluids.py $pressure $temp $fluid");

I also tried to run some more basic scripts, like a script which just prints "Hello world !", and it failed as well.
And I tried using exec() function instead of shell_exec(), without any results.
The script I have (usePyfluids.py) do work when called from a command shell, but not when called by my PHP website.
This python script takes 3 parameters, makes a calculation out of it (from a library), and returns the result as a JSON. It is not configured to return NULL in any case, or otherwise the library is doing it. But since the script works from a shell, I assume it's not the library's fault. The script only requires 3 imports: pyfluids (the librairy), json and sys (to acess arguments). I've never had any errors with the script itself.

Apache connect to System...do you mean that Apache is running under an identity called "System"? Or if not, what identity does the Apache process run as? That identity will need permission to access the folder where the python script is stored, for example. Possibly this has changed as a result of you switching from xampp to wamp, as it may install Apache differently - I'm not aware of the specifics though, you would need to check.

You should start by testing a minimal Python script like print("Test").

If you want to use the absolute path, then you must escape backslashes. "\f" is a formfeed character, which is not what you want. Alternatively you can use forward slashes (as you did already in python/usePyfluids.py). And remove those single quotes; they have nothing to do here. Finally, the Python executable is python3.exe, not python3.

@ADyson what I mean is that Apache do use the System "user" to access PATH variable. The Python script is stored where in the website folder so it does have the access to it.

@Olivier Basic script like the one you suggested will succeed if written in a console, but it'll fail if it's called by PHP.

@Olivier I just changed the code a bit :

In my Python, I just have print('Hello')
In PHP, I call Python like this :
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3.exe python/usePyfluids.py");
$result = shell_exec($command);

Result is still null

Try with the absolute path of Python. Make sure you write it properly and that file_exists() returns true on it. And don't use escapeshellcmd().

Even with absolute path of Python, nothing seems to work. file_exists does return true. And I use escapeshellcmd() because I will have arguments to use and I want it to be secure.
Also I just reinstalled Python, put it back to the PATH variable, and still nothing changes. I can use Python from any console, but I can't call it from PHP.

Apache do use the System "user" to access PATH variable...having access to an environment variable such as PATH has nothing to do with having access to the actual folders and files you're trying to use. Apache needs access to a) the python executable and b) the .py script you're trying to run

@ADyson Okay.. How do I check for that ? I didn't configure anything on XAMP to be able to use Python so I don't know what to look for

It's not about xampp, it's just your standard filesystem permissions. If the Apache process runs as "System" then check that the Windows "System" account has at least read access to the python executable and the .py script

On the other hand, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts#default-local-system-accounts you may not be able to do that, and/or SYSTEM may already have permission to anything. It sounds like that is not a great account for Apache to be running as, tbh

@ADyson Okay, so I should change the "user" that Apache is using ?

Possibly. We don't have any concrete error messages or anything like that to work with, so I'm only speculating that permissions are causing a problem. But it's something to check carefully, and try out. Remember any new account will also need sufficient other privileges to do the rest of the webserver's job. You may be able to do some research online about how people usually run Apache on Windows

@ADyson I tried to go to the python file directly from localhost, and I got an error 500 Internal Server Error, apart from that I can only provide the apache error logs

Surely you have a php error log? If not, configure php to log errors. Also make sure you're echoing $result to see what shell_exec() returns. Your code sample doesn't show that you're doing that

I tried to go to the python file directly from localhost...1) I doubt apache is set up to process python scripts directly, unless you've changed the setup, 2) is the python script even under the web root folder?

@ADyson I do enabled the php_errors in my php.ini, but I don't see any errors about PHP not being able to execute the script. I do echo $result and it's always NULL. And my Python script is inside the website folder, which is in the web root folder.
I did manage to make it work again but it was in a IIS server, not Wamp.

Ok. What does the python script usePyfluids.py actually do? Are there any conditions under which it might legitimately return NULL/empty? Does that script itself need access to any resources which might require permissions to be set? Have you got any error logging set up within the python script itself? We need to rule out everything that could possibly go wrong, and narrow down the issue.

@ADyson This script takes 3 parameters, makes a calculation out of it (from a librairy), and returns the result as a JSON. It is not configured to return NULL in any case, or otherwise the librairy is doing it. But since the script works from a shell, I assume it's not the librairy's fault.
The script only requires 3 imports, pyfluids (the librairy), json and sys (to acess arguments). I've never had any errors with the script itself.
